# Angular, How to set row ID with *ngFor or any repetition for HTML-table

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I want to set an ID for each rows dynamically ngFor 
 or any repetition in Angular.

```html
<div *ngFor="let d of data | async">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So anyone can help me how to make the rows have IDs like `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case, there is no need to use extra `index` variable:

> This will save bit processing from frontend side as it doen't have to
>   maintain any index varible.

Just use :

```
<tr [attr.id]="d.id">
```

Inplace of

```
<tr id="row">
```

Comment: i think he should because id could have different values

Comment: a very smart and simple solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **`index`** and assign to rowId and use

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data; let rowId= index | async">
```

and then

```
 <tr [attr.id]=rowId>
    <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: so the tr become like this `<tr id="rowId">`? CMIIW

Comment: simply use  <tr   [attr.id]=rowId>

Answer (score 3):

You can try bellow code

```
<div *ngFor="let d of (data | async) ; let i = index">
            <table border=1>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
                <tr id="row{{1+i}}">
                    <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ d.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

use the below code:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data ; let i=index | async">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
            <tr id="row{{i+1}}">
                <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```